# How to handle file path in multiplatform way (both win/Unix)?

Tags: python-3.x, filepath

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
```

#create dir for files as it could be non-existent

```
directory = ROOT_DIR + CFG_FILE_RECPATH
```

Under win env CFG_FILE_RECPATH have to be like `\\upload\`
But under Ubuntu `/upload/`

For the moment I change the d limitter literal from '\' to '/' is it good enough?

Comment: You should look at [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). But for the simple case of joining you can also use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) function.

```py
directory = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, CFG_FILE_RECPATH)
```